# How to retrieve JSON data located in a different file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have 6 json files in the same directory as my index.htm. Each json structure has saved game data in it. I want to let the user choose a file and load its associated json data structure. How can I go about retrieving that data?

I tried using

```
var myjson = new Object();
$.getJSON("myJSON.json", function(json) {
  myjson = JSON.stringify(json);
  console.log(myjson);
});
```

This gives me an XMLHttpRequest error (cross-origin request not supported).

Comment: you can't AJAX file:/// protocol - you are doing this on http:// or https:// correct?

Comment: Look at your Developer Tools Network panel, refresh your page, run your script. What is your page's URL, and what is the Ajax URL?

Comment: I'm just doing this locally. My url is file:///C:/Users/Kevin/workspace/Flow/WebContent/index.htm

Comment: try to setup a http server on localhost.. very easy to do. do that first to get a proper dev environment up and running

Answer (score 1):

Your execution is fine -- though like the comments on your post suggest, you need to change the protocol you're using.  Really just load the HTML page using `http://127.0.0.1/mypage.html` instead of `file://home/website/mypage.html` and you can likely keep your javascript the same.

Aside from this, you might want to consider the data in your `myJSON.json` file.  I noticed if the JSON data contains `function` definitions then it will cause `$.ajax()` or in this case `$.getJSON()` to throw a parse error.

So this will not work

```
{
    "json" : function () {
        alert("HI");
    },
    "hello" : 432
}
```

But this will work

```
{
    "json" : "5",
    "hello" : 432
}
```